# Dart inheritance progress

Tags: dart

I'm a **newer** of **dart**.recently I found a question from my study.

my code is below:

```dart
class TwoD {
  double x, y;
  
  TwoD({ this.x, this.y });
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'x: ${this.x}, y: ${this.y}';
  }
}

class ThreeD extends TwoD{
  double z;
  ThreeD({ x = 3, y, this.z }): super(x: x = 100.0, y: y);
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    return '${super.toString()}, z: ${this.z}';
  }
}

ThreeD point = ThreeD(x: 1.9, y: 2.0, z: 3.0);
  
void main() {
  print(point.x);
  print(point.y);
  print(point.z);
  print(point.toString());
}
```

In **ThreeD sub class**, I set a **default** [I'm not sure yet.] value of **super.x**, then I found that the **x** value of all instances I created is 100, I have known it's a serious bug and I want to know why lead this, or could someone teach me the progress of extending? I have read the tour part of dart.

Thank you very much! have a nice day!

Comment: Can you explain the reason for `x = 100.0` in this `super(x: x = 100.0, y: y)`?

Comment: @julemand101 I did it on purpose, I wanted to know what happened. lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be seen in the following example:

```
void main() {
  var x = 5;
  print(x = 10); // 10
  print(x);      // 10
}
```

So the statement `x = 10` will set `x` to the value `10` but will at the same time return `10` which are then picked up by `print` in this example. The reason for this is it will allow us to write stuff like:

```
void main() {
  int x, y, z;
  x = y = z = 10;

  print(x); // 10
  print(y); // 10
  print(z); // 10
}
```

Since `z = 10` will return `10` which we then use for `y = 10` which then are used for `x = 10`.

Your problem is the following line:

```
ThreeD({ x = 3, y, this.z }): super(x: x = 100.0, y: y);
```

Here, `x = 100.0` will return `100` which are then used like `x: 100.0` so we are setting the `x` parameter in `super` to `100.0`.

As for a fix, I really need to know the reason for this `100.0` but my best guess would be just remove it since you already have defined a default value with `double x = 3` so if `x` are not defined it will automatically get the value `3`:

```
ThreeD({double x = 3, double y, this.z}) : super(x: x, y: y);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug. The `super` keyword is used to call the constructor of the base class, thus overwriting it. Everything that comes *after* the comma is an [initializer list](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list), which executes before the superclass is called.

So, in your example, every instance of `ThreeD` is generated already having a value of `100` to `x`.

If you want to set `100` if `x` is null, for instance, you could do add an [*if null*](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions) operator (expr1 ?? expr2):

```dart
class ThreeD extends TwoD{
  double z;
  ThreeD({ x, y, this.z }): super(x: x ?? 100.0, y: y);
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    return '${super.toString()}, z: ${this.z}';
  }
}
```

For more information in constructors, you can check the [language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors).

Comment: Thank you very much. I learn something more from you.